# R interprets points and comma's as column separators, despite specifying 'sep=","' and 'quote = ""'

Tags: r, multiple-columns, quote

R interprets points and comma's as column separators, despite specifying `sep=","` and `quote = ""`.

The following code was used:

```
#Read in the egg data from CSV file
RE_rough<-read.csv("C:/Users/Jolie/OneDrive - KU Leuven/1e mast/Semester 2/Engineering Properties of Biological Materials/Practica/2. Texture + acoustics/Eggdatacsv.csv", header = F, sep = ",", quote = "")
```

The number of columns do not match the number of column names. After this command line, I get 13 columns instead of 7. I do not understand why R interpret the points as column separators after specifying it.

Did I something wrong when preparing the CSV file?
How can I load this data in R?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help you, we really need to see your csv file. For instance, is it possible that some of its values use comma as a thousands (say 1,000,000 for one million) or decimal separator (3,142 as an approximation for pi)?